# A homotopy that sends all zeros to $0$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-topology

> Let $f ∶ S^2 = \mathbb{C} ∪ \{\infty\} → S^2$ be define by $f(z) = z^n$.
>
> If $p$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$, then $p$ is homotopic to $f$ via the homotopy that sends all zeros to $0$.

Can't understand what this means... what does it mean for a homotopy to send all zeros to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your polynomial $p(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n (z - a_i)$, where the $a_i$ are the roots ("zeroes") of the polynomial $p$. Then define the homotopy $H(z,t) = \prod_{i=1}^n (z - t a_i)$; basically it "sends all the roots to zero". This is clearly continuous, and $H(z,0) = z^n$ while $H(z,1) = p(z)$, so $p$ and $z \mapsto z^n$ are homotopic.